# No adapter attached; skipping layout error

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm developing Android application that must show all images stored inside SD card. I did it successfully except I getting strange behavior when switching to landscape mode (in fact, I do not see anything in my grid).

In logcat I get this message :
RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout

Yes, I am using RecyclerView and this only happens in landscape, when I rotate back to portrait again, Fragment is retained and I can see every single bitmap inside my grid again.

Now, does anyone know why this is happening to me ?
Here is how I set my adapter to recyclerView (inside a fragment):

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, imageManager);
        imagesGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Oh, and by the way, I am using default GridLayoutManager for RecyclerView.

Comment: My guess is that onLoadFinished() is only being called once when your app starts. Set a breakpoint there and check if it runs when you switch from portrait to landscape. My guess is it does not and thus, adapter is null.

Comment: I recently read that this error occurs when adapter is null. But how should I set adapter in onCreateView when I need a cursor to set it up ?
Is it only possible way to update RecyclerView.Adapter with CursorAdapter methods ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're unable to get the cursor somewhere else, like in onResume?

Comment: Well, I'm using default CursorLoader and calling initLoeader() inside onCreateView(). How should I get returned cursor in onResume ? In the other hand, initLoader should be called every time when fragment is recreated (because this metod is inside onCreateView method).

Comment: Can you help me out with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30524798/some-data-not-set-by-recycler-adater