# Some data not set by Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

This is my on createView. I see in the log cat that all the data is available but some of the data is not set in the adapter. The balance card is not a part of the recycler view. This is done in a fragment. When the oncreate view of this fragment is called i get the error No adapter attached; skipping layout error. I think that it expects me to attach an adapter as soon as i initialize the recycler view but since i am attaching an adapter after getting all the data so it may be throwing the error but still i dont have an explanation for data that is not seen in some view.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment,null);
            currentBalance = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_balance);

            paymentsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.payments_recycler_view);
            Constants.paymentsData = new ArrayList<PaymentsData>();

            paymentsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            paymentsLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            paymentsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(paymentsLayoutManager);


            new FetchPaymentAsyncTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),new FetchPaymentAsyncTask.FetchPaymentCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStart(boolean a) {

                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    dialog.setTitle("Getting Your Payment Details");
                    dialog.setMessage("Loading... please wait");
                    dialog.show();
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);

                }
                @Override
                public void onResult(boolean b) {

                    if(b){
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        currentBalance.setText(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+Constants.currentBalance);
                        paymentsAdapter = new PaymentsAdapter(Constants.paymentsData, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        paymentsRecyclerView.setAdapter(paymentsAdapter);

                    }
                    else{
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                        builder.setTitle("Payment Details");
                        builder.setMessage("No Payment Records");
                        builder.show();

                    }

                }
            }).execute(Constants.fetchPaymentURL+Constants.merchantId);
            return rootView;
        }
```

[image: Result of adapter]

[image: Log Cat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It was with Adapter class where i played with the VISIBILITY. Thanx for the help